# Ant xmlproperty task. What happens when there is more than one tag with the same name?

Tags: xml, ant

I am trying to follow a large ant buildfile that I have been given, and I am having trouble understanding the functionality of xmlproperty in this case.
Consider this xml file, example.xml.

```
<main>
  <tagList>
    <tag>
      <file>file1</file>
      <machine>machine1</machine>
    </tag>
    <tag>
      <file>file2</file>
      <machine>machine2</machine>
    </tag>
  </tagList>
</main>
```

In the buildfile, there is a task which can be simplified to the following for this example:

```
<xmlproperty file="example.xml" prefix="PREFIX" />
```

As I understand it, if there was only one `<tag>` element, I could get the contents of `<file>` with `${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file}`
because it is roughly equivalent to writing this:

```
<property name="PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file" value="file1"/>
```

But as there are two `<tag>`s, what is the value of `${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file}` in this case? If it is some sort of list, how do I iterate through both `<file>` values?

I am using ant 1.6.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When multiple elements have the same name, `<xmlproperty>` creates a property with comma-separated values:

```
<project name="ant-xmlproperty-with-multiple-matching-elements" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <xmlproperty file="example.xml" prefix="PREFIX" />

        <echo>${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The result:

```
run:
     [echo] file1,file2
```

To process the comma-separated values, consider using [the `<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) from the third-party Ant-Contrib library:

```
<project 
    name="ant-xmlproperty-with-multiple-matching-elements" 
    default="run" 
    basedir="." 
    xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib"
    >
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <target name="run">
        <xmlproperty file="example.xml" prefix="PREFIX" />

        <ac:for list="${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file}" param="file">
            <sequential>
                <echo>@{file}</echo>
            </sequential>
        </ac:for>
    </target>
</project>
```

The result:

```
run:
     [echo] file1
     [echo] file2
```

Comment: great explanation, thanks. To clarify for anyone else who reads this, it seems that the <for> tag loops over a comma delimiter by default, which works nicely with the identical xmlproperty default delimeter.

Comment: Suppose each `<tag>` had a unique attribute value. Would there be a way to access the value of the property using that attribute value instead of using Ant-Contrib?