# Ant task to get value of repeating XML element

Tags: ant

I have the following requirement.

from [Ant xmlproperty task. What happens when there is more than one tag with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356605/ant-xmlproperty-task-what-happens-when-there-is-more-than-one-tag-with-the-same)
it's clear how to repeat for each file.
My requirement is to iterate for each file and I would like to  get the value of 'machine' element for corresponding file
eg:

```
<echo>${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file[file1]}</echo> // should return machine1

<echo>${PREFIX.main.tagList.tag.file[file2]}</echo> // should return machine2
```

Answer (score 0):

An example would help, but I think I discovered this limitation in the xmlproperty task before. For performing complex processing of external files I would use an embedded groovy task, which just loves XML :-)

You haven't specified a sample input, so here's a similar example:

- [Parse HTML using with an Ant Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script/7435804#7435804)