# Get XML property when there is more than one property that matches

Tags: xml, ant

I have an XML file like this:

```
<vrmlist>
    <vrm version="4" product="prod1" platform="windows"/>
    <vrm version="1" product="prod1" platform="web"/>
    <vrm version="6" product="prod2" platform="windows"/>
</vrmlist>
```

The file is used for other purposes so changing it's structure would be difficult. I would like to access the version for each item independently using the `<xmlproperty>` task.

Example

```
<xmlproperty file="test.xml"/>

<target name="test">
    <echo>Version: ${vrmlist.vrm(version)}</echo>
</target>
```

Results in

```
test:
     [echo] Version: 4,1,6
```

What I want is to be able do is access the properties for each `<vrm>` independently for a given product and platform so I can use it in the build file.

Example of what I want (does not work):

```
<echo>${vrmlist.vrm[@product="prod1" and @platform="windows"](version)}</echo>

Test:
    [echo] Version: 4
```

Is this possible?

Similar question: [Ant xmlproperty task. What happens when there is more than one tag with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356605/ant-xmlproperty-task-what-happens-when-there-is-more-than-one-tag-with-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

The free, third-party [XmlTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) library can extract XML values with XPath:

### build.xml

```
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
<xmltask>
    <fileset file="src.xml"/>
    <copy
        path="/vrmlist/vrm[@product='prod1' and @platform='windows']/@version"
        property="vrm.version"/>
</xmltask>
<echo>vrm.version : ${vrm.version}</echo>
```

### Output

```
run:
     [echo] vrm.version : 4
```